# What will be the logic to show top rated item?

Tags: rating-system

I want to show items in my website sorted by its rating. 
I don't want to show highest rated items by the average of rating. Could anyone suggest some formula to define highest rated item.

Comment: More information imperative ..

Comment: What language, do you have a database what kind etc please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

You could weight each item's average rating by the number of people who have entered in a rating. This would ensure items with both high number of rating and high average rating would float to the top instead of just items with a singular rating.

```
projectedRating = item.AverageRating * item.Ratings.Count
```

Additionally, you could consider normalizing this so it only makes a difference between say 1 and 100 rating applied.

```
projectedRating = item.AverageRating * Max(item.Ratings.Count, 100)
```

This way run away votes on an item, even with a low average rating, wouldn't end up on the top all the time.

Outside of that, I think you'll need to provide more information on what basis you'd like to indicate an item is a top item. Total views on it, marking it as most popular, could be an option as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the score for an item is likely to be a function of:

- Average rating
- Highest rating, lowest rating
- Number of rates
- A time weighting